# SharePoint 2013 People Search not appearing in search results

Tags: 2013

I have enabled user profile synchronization service.

In my site collection when I search, people results are not coming up

[image]

What else should I configure/enable to make the people tab appear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Central Administration navigate to Manage Service Applications in the section Application Management or use the direct URL http://CentralAdminURL:port/_admin/ServiceApplications.aspx

Select the row of the User Profile Service Application and click "Administrators" in the ribbon. Add the SP_SearchContent account as administrator and give it the "Retrieve People Data for Search Crawlers" permission.

[image]

Provided that you meet all the prerequisites:

- Managed Metadata Service
- Search Service Application (crawling sps3://My_Site_host_URL)
- User Profile Service Application (with synced profiles)
- MySite Host

See: [Deploy people search in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582311.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

Did you completed a full crawl or a incremental crawl on the farm? Set it to run late in the night when no one is using the environment(this process will use a lot of memory). After that, in max 24 H you should have your people in the search engine. Remember!For any new content you need to run crawls. You can set different kind of crawls and set them to run once per hour/day/week/month, based on how fast is that content updating. All of them should run late in the night or in weekend days.

For the "people" to apear into the results page you should verify this location and see if you have there a page named "people", if not...create it and configure the webpart(Press "edit page" to results page):

1.
[image: ![enter image description here]

2. [image]
3. [image]